# Protractor sync vs async

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

I understand that jasmine/protractor you can use `then` to wait for the result of certain operations. I also sort of understand how the Control flow works.

My question is, if I have to use a `then` do all subsequent operations need to be chained in `then`? Or would protractor take care of synchronicity?

I am using page model:

```
SomePage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    list: { get: () => {return element.all(by.repeater("item in $ctrl.list"))}}
});

somePage.list.then((listItems) => {
    expect(list.length).toBe(1);
    element(by.css(".item-name")).getText().then((itemName) => {
        expect(itemName).toBe("test item");
    });
})
```

to further test, do I do:

```
somePage.list.then((listItems) => { 
    ... 
})
.then(() => {
    ... more testing
});
```

or do i just continue as if sync?

Follow up question: 
when using  a Page model, for page functions that trigger a click event that triggers a http call in the application, should they `return element(by.css('some-button-that-triggers-a-http')).click()` or just execute the click?

Comment: Not sure about the click, but you will need to chain `then`s if you are testing anything dependent on the listItems. If you want it to be more compact you could just place it in a beforeEach, and your later `it( ... )`s will be run sync.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there's also a whenRenderingDone().then( ... ) method you can use as well.

Answer (score 0):

If depends on whether you need to call additional asynchronous operations inside your `then`.  If so, you can chain the then's.  If not, you would continue with synchronous code inside your 'then' statement.

You've got a typo -- make sure you call list, as in:

```
somePage.list().then((listItems) => { 
    ... 
})
```

Finally, make sure you call `done()` inside your `then` statement so that jasmine knows the test has finished running.  (Or just use the es6+ `async / await`)